# Matrix Ring over a Division Ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, division-ring

What is the definition of a matrix ring over a division ring? Hungerford mentions this in one of his examples but does not define what it is. Is it simply a matrix ring with entries of a division ring? Thank you.

Comment: yes, that is what it is.